# ir sequence increment issue in odoo

Tags: odoo

Hi guys Help me with this.

the check field doesnt increment.it stays blank

```py
from odoo import api, fields, models, _

class check_print(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment'

    check = fields.Char("Check Number",readonly=True)

    @api.model
    def create(self,vals):
        if vals.get('payment_method_code') == ('check_printing'):
            vals['check'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('seq.ch.code')
            res = super(check_print, self).create(vals)
            return res
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <odoo>
      <data noupdate="1">
         <record id="seq_check_id" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">check</field>
            <field name="code">seq.ch.code</field>
            <field name="prefix">CH</field>
            <field name="padding">10</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

the check field is empty everytime i save the record

Comment: Show us your `seq.ch.code` sequence as well

Comment: any idea...whats wrong

Comment: What is this? `('check_printing')` Do you possibly mean `('check_printing', )` or `'check_printing'`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this line is not being evaluated to True:

```
if vals.get('payment_method_code') == ('check_printing'):
```

Also check your indentation of this lines that need to be outside the `if` block

```
res = super(check_print, self).create(vals)
return res
```

Comment: changed the indentation right after if block but no effect.                                          if vals.get('payment_method_code') == ('check_printing'):                                  whats wrong with this code....

Comment: Seems that `vals.get('payment_method_code')` is not equals to `('check_printing')` so no sequence code is generated